# Monitoring of Network

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

We have around 300 machines. How can we monitor the network using an Ubuntu machine so that we can find out which node is broadcasting, traffic monitoring, also trying ntop.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**snmpd**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/snmpd) [image: Install snmpd] and 
 [**cacti**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cacti) [image: Install cacti]

Check out **[this guide](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-monitor-your-servers-with-snmp-and-cacti)**

Comment: +1 good recommendations and package links. In general, it is better to say "Check out how-to-monitor-your-servers-with-snmp-and-cacti at debuntu.org" rather than "this link" as it is more descriptive and doesn't break if debuntu.org goes off the net.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of monitoring solutions out there.

[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) might be an option for your needs, take a look at [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) and use [kSar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksar/) to visualize the results.

Your choice depends on the needs you have.

Answer (score 1):

[karthick87](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18706/monitoring-of-network/18707#18707) has the answer, but just to amplify it your monitoring has to be distributed amongst the 300 end-stations and cannot be simply centralized to one point.

The biggest reason this is necessary is that you are probably using a switched (not shared) network hub so no single point is capable of seeing all the traffic on the net. SNMP is certainly old-school, partly because it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [bijk](http://www.bijk.com/), is free only for one server. Is a commercial solution and you can use it with a lot of Linux distributions (and of course with Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

My personal tool of choice is wireshark.  It has a nice gui, flexible filters, and a some analysing tools.

sudo apt-get install wireshark