# Internet Monitoring & Control tools

Tags: networking, bandwidth, network-monitoring

I'm looking for an application for monitoring internet usage and controlling bandwidth speed and quotas for each user/MAC in a centralized server for a small LAN network (less than 100 PCs).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  You want to monitor bandwidth from each machine, from each user on each machine, or traffic from different users only to/from the server?   Or something else?  Are you trying to controlling bandwidth centrally or from each node?

Comment: hi @jgbelacqua, i want to control bandwidth centrally and the traffic from different users to/from server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the solutions in these questions (I've included some of the top suggestions, where they are packages):

[How do I limit internet bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/limit-internet-bandwidth)

- [wondershaper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wondershaper) [image: Install wondershaper]
- [trickle](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trickle) [image: Install trickle]

[How to limit internet speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18038/how-to-limit-internet-speed)

- wondershaper with [mastershaper front-end](http://www.mastershaper.org/index.php/Main_Page)

[Monitoring of Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18706/monitoring-of-network)

- [snmpd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/snmpd)[image: Install snmpd]
- [cacti](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cacti) [image: Install cacti]

[How can you monitor internet data usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-download-usage)

- [ntop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ntop) [image: Install ntop]

[How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth)

- iptraf
- nethogs
- iftop

Comment: If those don't do what you need, ask again with your refined requirements and I'm sure I or someone else can offer more suggestions.